Is R portable safe for sensitive data?
I'm planning to create an r script that I will share with other coworkers to automate some tasks in their jobs. The idea is to share a zip file with a portable version of R with all the libraries needed already installed and then they will just put the data in some specific folder and run a batch file that will run the script.
I download the portable version here
https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/R-Portable/4.2.0/
but how I check if it has some malicious code that can take private company data?
I'm using r-portable for the first time so I'm not sure if it's possible to share the package already installed in a local folder as a zip with libraries already installed.

In my experience, the standard R install straight from r-project.org is pretty "portable" if you don't want to use the Sourceforge download. I ran R off a memory stick for a number of years by just copying the whole folder over. Just put all the needed packages in the R-X.X.X\library folder.

@thelatemail do you mean to say that I don't need a portable R, just copy the default R installation folder and share it and it will work normally? I thought that when a regular installation was carried out, records were created in the system that would be necessary for it to function. I will try this approach tomorrow.

Yep. Give it a go and see how it works for you.

The IT dept at my old workplace was very slow to action anything and were less than enthusiastic when it came to continually adding and updating packages. I ended up doing what @thelatemail suggested and it worked very well. I was running RStudio from the same flash dive, which was copied using the same method e.g. copy the whole RStudio directory from C:\Program Files (or wherever it is stored on your machine).

Could you also do this with a Shiny App hosted at (e.g.) shinyapps.io? As far as I understand it apps hosted there are secure as long as you don't create an opening for code injection
